# Live display new added photos from google drive api

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api, service-accounts, google-api-nodejs-client

Using Google drive Api and a service account I get photos from google drive, all the photos that were originally on the drive are displayed correctly, but if I add a new photo to google drive, the photo itself is not displayed, only its name

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const path = require('path');

const getDriveService = () => {
  const KEYFILEPATH = path.join(__dirname, 'settings.json');
  const SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];

  const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: KEYFILEPATH,
    scopes: SCOPES,
  });
  const driveService = google.drive({ version: 'v3', auth });
  return driveService;
};


function getThumbnailUrl(fileId) {
  const timestamp = Date.now(); // Cache-busting parameter
  return `https://drive.google.com/thumbnail?id=${fileId}&timestamp=${timestamp}`;
}
export function getPhotosFromDrive() {
  const driveService = getDriveService();

  return driveService.files.list({
    q: "mimeType='image/jpeg' or mimeType='image/png'", // Filter for JPEG and PNG images
    fields: 'files(id, name, webViewLink)', // Specify the fields to retrieve
  })
    .then(response => {
      const photos = response.data.files;
      return photos.map(photo => ({
        name: photo.name,
        id: photo.id,
        webViewLink: getThumbnailUrl(photo.id)
      }));
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error retrieving photos:', error);
      throw error;
    });
}
```

```
import { getPhotosFromDrive } from 'backend/photosGallery';

$w.onReady(function () {
  getPhotosFromDrive()
    .then(photos => {
      const galleryItems = photos.map(photo => ({
        type: 'image',
        src: photo.webViewLink,
        title: photo.name
      }));

      $w('#gallery1').items = galleryItems;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error retrieving photos:', error);
      // Handle the error
    });
});
```

[image]

Comment: What do you get, when you try to open that image URL directly in a new tab?

Comment: do service accounts have webViewLink seeing as they have no access to the web app i wonder if they are even generated.

Comment: @CBroe, oops I got it:  Your client does not have permission to get the URL.  But why do I have no permission for new photos? they are all located in the folder, which is shared with to service email account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Suggestion

> *Since I do not have the complete details of your setup, I can only make guesses to help with the investigation. You can use this as a starting point for further troubleshooting.*

**Based on my own testing:**

- A newly added image pulled by the `Service Account` *(from a Google Drive folder shared with the Service Account's email)* displays a broken image icon on a test html web-page to show the image link:

  [image]
- When I opened the link of the broken image directly, I encountered the following:

  [image]
- To resolve the issue, I have tried changing the image's General access permission in Google Drive from "**Restricted**" to "**Anyone with the link**", allowing it to be publicly accessible and visible on my test:

  [image]

## Reference

- [*Google Drive: Share a file publicly*](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494822#share_publicly&zippy=%2Cshare-a-file-publicly)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What I meant by "we" are the community members in Stackoverflow. Corrected it now. Thanks for pointing it out.